# Create an empty command

Tags: macros, r

In my research, I do my analysis in R and write the paper in LaTeX. To avoid updating values in the paper when my analysis change, I update the values in the paper directly from R.

Assume in R I have the variable `foo <- bar`.

Right now, I have a placeholder in LaTeX with a set of brackets for `foo`'s value and then a label so that R can find the correct brackets to put the values in.

One example with `foo <- bar` could be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {}\label{R.foo}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

So R finds a predefined label (in this case, `R.foo`), and then replaces whatever is inside the first brackets with `foo`'s value (here: `bar`). So after R runs, we'll have:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {bar}\label{R.foo}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

The problem is that we'll get multiply defined labels (since there are multiple `\label{R.foo}` locations still left within the file after R processing is complete), which my LaTeX editor warns me about. Hence, I try to create an alternative that has no LaTeX functionality whatsoever—it should just be something R can search for.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1:

[As suggested by Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629749/118714) use **[knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/)**. Have [knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/) create the .tex-file for you from an .Rnw-file or .Rtex-file where R-code-chunks and TeX-code are merged and where at the time of creating the .tex-file the results of carrying out R-code-chunks are placed into the .tex-file. (knitr works out of the box with the online-TeX-platform [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) if the file to compile does not have the extension ".tex" but does have the extension ".Rtex".)

With the following knitr-example, which must be saved with filename-extension ".Rtex" the R-code-chunks calculate Pythagorean triples:

```latex
<<templates, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
knitr::opts_template$set(
  JustResult = list(include=TRUE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis')
)
PrintTriple <- function(k, s, t) {
    return(cat(
      "With \\(k=", k, "\\) and \\(s=", s, "\\) and \\(t=", t, "\\) you get \\(a=", (k*2*s*t), "\\), \\(b=", (k*((s*s)-(t*t))),
      "\\) and \\(c=", (k*((s*s)+(t*t))), "\\) and \\mbox{\\(a^2+b^2=c^2\\leftrightarrow(",
      (k*2*s*t),")^2+(",(k*((s*s)-(t*t))),")^2=(",(k*((s*s)+(t*t))),")^2","\\)}."
      , sep="", fill=FALSE
    ))
}
@

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ggd}{ggd}

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\medskipamount

\begin{document}

Use the following recipe to calculate triples
\((a, b, c)\) where the condition \(((a^2+b^2=c^2)\land(\{a,b,c\}\subset\mathbb{N})\land((a\equiv0\pmod{2}))\) is fulfilled---such triples are called \textbf{Pythagorean triples}:

Choose natural numbers \(k,s,t\); \(s>t\) and set:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a &\longleftarrow k2st\\
b &\longleftarrow k(s^2-t^2)\\
c &\longleftarrow k(s^2+t^2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

(If and only if \((k=1)\land(\gcd(s,t) = 1)\land(s\not\equiv t \pmod{2})\), then \((a, b, c)\) is called a \textbf{primitive} Pythagorean triple.)

\noindent
<<, opts.label='JustResult' >>=
PrintTriple(2, 4, 3)
@

\noindent
<<, opts.label='JustResult' >>=
PrintTriple(2, 3, 1)
@

\noindent
<<, opts.label='JustResult' >>=
K=1
S=2
T=1
PrintTriple(K, S, T)
@

\noindent
<<, opts.label='JustResult' >>=
K=3*K
S=2
T=1
PrintTriple(K, S, T)
@

\noindent
<<, opts.label='JustResult' >>=
S=3*S
T=3*T
PrintTriple(K, S, T)
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Approach 2:

Probably your R-program could write a .tex-file `ValuesCalculatedByR.tex` with content like

```latex
cathetus1={3,3},
cathetus2={4,4},
hypotenuse={5,5},
```

, i.e., a comma-separated list of pattern *⟨identificator⟩*={*⟨calculated value⟩*}.

(The curly braces surrounding the *⟨calculated value⟩*s can be omitted if the *⟨calculated value⟩*s themselves do not contain commata and if you don't mind spaces that surround *⟨calculated value⟩*s being removed.)

And the .tex-file could make an expl3-property-list from it and define a command so that `\command{<identificator>}` yields  `<calculated value>`:

```
% I don't have R available right now for creating the file, thus I let the filecontents*-
% environment do that for me:
\begin{filecontents*}{ValuesCalculatedByR.tex}
cathetus1={3,3},
cathetus2={4,4},
hypotenuse={5,5},
FirstTokenIsExpandable=\LaTeX\space is funny and the value is defined.,
\end{filecontents*}
% The <value> "\LaTeX\space is funny and the value is defined."
% of the <identificator> "FirstTokenIsExpandable" does not
% contain comma, thus surrounding curly braces can be omitted.

\ExplSyntaxOn
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \ImportIDValueList{<.tex-input-file containing list of pattern <identificator>={<calculated value>} >}
%                   {<command for retrieving <calculated value> associated to <identifictor> >}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ImportIDValueList #1#2 {
  % #1 = name of .tex-input-file created by the program R
  % #2 = to-be-defined command for retrieving calculated value
  \exp_args:Nno \use:n 
                { \exp_args:Nno \use:n { \__Christian_ImportIDValueList:nn{#1} } } 
                { \cs_to_str:N #2 }
}
\cs_new:Nn \__Christian_ImportIDValueList:nn{
  % #1 = name of .tex-input-file created by the program R
  % #2 = name of to-be-defined command for retrieving calculated value
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #2 } ##1 { 
    \exp:w \__Christian_ImportValue_GetValue:nnnn { #1 } { Christian_ImportValue_#2_prop } {##1} {
      \msg_error:nnnnn { Christian_ImportValue } { not-available } { #1 } { ##1 }
      \mbox{\textsf{?##1?}}
    } 
  }
  \cs_new:cpn { #2Expandable } ##1 ##2 { 
    \exp:w \__Christian_ImportValue_GetValue:nnnn { #1 } { Christian_ImportValue_#2_prop } {##1} { ##2 } 
  }
  \file_get:nnN {#1} {} {\l_tmpa_tl}
  \prop_gclear_new:c { Christian_ImportValue_#2_prop }
  % Can't use \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn  because ~ needs to be before each <value> as 
  % - unlike unexpandable x-expansion of \prop_item:cn - expandable f-expansion of \prop_item:cn 
  % won't stop when \prop_item:cn has delivered the result and therefore
  % must be stopped by a ~ that gets gobbled by the f-expansion-
  % routine, which, I guess, is s.th. like "\romannumeral-`a"
  % so that expansion during parsing the <number>-quantity
  % continues until it is clear whether a to-be-discarded <optional
  % space> follows the tokens "-`a" denoting the negative number -97
  % while \romannumeral silently removes tokens denoting TeX-
  % <number>-quantities denoting non-positive values without
  % returning any tokens at all.
  \exp_args:NnV \use:n {
    \keyval_parse:nnn 
      { \__Christian_ImportValue_pass_iii_ii_to_i {\__Christian_ImportValue_propset:nnn { Christian_ImportValue_#2_prop }}{} }
      { \__Christian_ImportValue_propset:nnn { Christian_ImportValue_#2_prop } } 
  } { \l_tmpa_tl }
}
\cs_new:Nn \__Christian_ImportValue_pass_iii_ii_to_i:nnn { #1 {#3} {#2} }
\cs_new:Nn \__Christian_ImportValue_propset:nnn {
  \prop_gput:cnn {#1} {#2} {~#3}
}
\cs_new:Nn \__Christian_ImportValue_GetValue:nnnn {
  % #1 = name of .tex-input-file created by the program R
  % #2 = name of property list
  % #3 = value to be retrieved from of property list
  % #4 = tokens in case property is undefined
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { #2 } { #3 }
                   { \exp_args:Nnf \use:nn {\exp_end:} { \prop_item:cn { #2 }{ #3 } } }
                   { \exp_end: #4 }
}
\msg_new:nnnn { Christian_ImportValue } { not-available }
 { Value~for~identifier~"#2"~could~not~be~retrieved }
 { Seems~the~file~"#1"~does~not~have~"#2=...,"}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}

\ImportIDValueList{ValuesCalculatedByR.tex}{\GetRValue}%
% The above 
% - makes a property-list of name "Christian_ImportValue_GetRValue_prop"
%   from the content of the file ValuesCalculatedByR.tex  and 
% - defines a command  \GetRValue{<property>} to check if <property> is defined
%   in the property-list "Christian_ImportValue_GetRValue_prop".
%   If so, the value of that property is delivered.
%   If not so, an error-message is raised and ?<name of property>? is delivered.
%   The command is not expandable but protected.
% - defines a command  \GetRValueExpandable{<property>}{<tokens if <property> is undefined>} 
%   to check if <property> is defined in the property-list "Christian_ImportValue_GetRValue_prop".
%   If so, the value of that property is delivered.
%   If not so, <tokens if <property> is not available> is delivered.
%   The command is expandable.
%   The result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps.
%   This might be important in case you need to "lay hands" on the result for
%   further examination. E.g., you may wish to have LaTeX examine the value
%   and fork the way of typesetting the value depending on whether the value does 
%   or does not contain a decimal separator. Or whatever.

\begin{document}

\noindent Unexpandable commands:\medskip

\noindent Test 1)\medskip

\[ (\GetRValue{cathetus1})^2+(\GetRValue{cathetus2})^2=(\GetRValue{hypotenuse})^2 \]

%% This yields an error-message and ?undefined value?:
% \GetRValue{undefined value}

\medskip\hrule\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Expandable commands:\medskip

\noindent Test a)\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Mytempa
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\GetRValueExpandable{cathetus1}{n/a}}%

\texttt{\string\Mytempa=\meaning\Mytempa}

\(\Mytempa\)

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Test b)\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Mytempb
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\GetRValueExpandable{cathetus2}{n/a}}

\texttt{\string\Mytempb=\meaning\Mytempb}

\(\Mytempb\)

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Test c)\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Mytempc
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\GetRValueExpandable{hypotenuse}{n/a}}

\texttt{\string\Mytempc=\meaning\Mytempc}

\(\Mytempc\)

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\[ (\Mytempa)^2+(\Mytempb)^2=(\Mytempc)^2 \]

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Test d)\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Mytempd
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\GetRValueExpandable
                                        {undefined value}%
                                        {\LaTeX\space is funny but the value
                                         ``undefined value'' is undefined.}%
                                    }

\texttt{\string\Mytempd=\meaning\Mytempd}

\Mytempd

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Test e)\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Mytempe
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\GetRValueExpandable{FirstTokenIsExpandable}{n/a}}

\texttt{\string\Mytempe=\meaning\Mytempe}

\Mytempe

\end{document}
```

[image]

This way the R-program would not need to do replacements in the .tex-file containing the document.
It would just need to create an additional text file containing a comma-separated *⟨identificator⟩*={*⟨calculated value⟩*}-list which then is loaded by LaTeX via

```
\ImportIDValueList{⟨file⟩}%
                  {⟨to‑be‑defined macro for retrieving a
                   ⟨calculated value⟩ stored in ⟨file⟩
                   by specifying an ⟨identificator⟩
                   in the argument⟩}%
```

.

---

Approach 3:

Have your R-program create a database in terms of a comma-separated-value-list stored as .csv-file, with fields "identificator" and "value" and use the package **datatool** for importing that database and retrieving values:

```latex
% With older LaTeX-kernels you need to activate/uncomment the following line:
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}

% I don't have R available right now for creating the file, thus I let the filecontents*-
% environment do that for me:
\begin{filecontents*}{ValuesCalculatedByR.csv}
cathetus1,"3,3"
cathetus2,"4,4"
hypotenuse,"5,5"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={identificator,value}]{ValuesCalculatedByR}{ValuesCalculatedByR.csv}

\newif\ifvaluenotfound
\newcommand\resultscratch{}%

\newcommand{\GetRValue}[1]{%
   \global\valuenotfoundtrue
   \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\identificator}{#1}]%
               {ValuesCalculatedByR}%
               {\identificator=identificator,\value=value}%
               {\global\valuenotfoundfalse\global\let\resultscratch=\value}%
   \ifvaluenotfound
     % Some error or warning-message could be here but I am too lazy at the moment.
     \textsf{?#1?}%
   \else
     \resultscratch
   \fi
}%


    
\begin{document}

\[ (\GetRValue{cathetus1})^2+(\GetRValue{cathetus2})^2=(\GetRValue{hypotenuse})^2 \]

%\GetRValue{Undefined}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would have R create a different file `values.tex` with the content

```tex
\newcommand{\Rfoo}{bar}
```

and then your main file would have

```tex
\input{values}
%\providecommand{\Rfoo}{} % avoid an error if \Rfoo wasn't defined
...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \Rfoo, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what are you trying to do exactly, but I think that is a unnecessarily messed approach. Consider use `knitr` to use `\Sexpr{}` to insert small R outputs (like a number or a vector) or R chunks (code between the `<<>>=` and `@` lines) for more  complex code (tables, plots, etc). Note that you can change the value of foo in any moment and  `\Sexpr{foo}` will be updated accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<Rchunkcode,echo=FALSE>>=
foo <- "bar" 
@
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \Sexpr{foo}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<<AnotherRchunkcode,echo=FALSE>>=
foo <- "baz" 
@
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \Sexpr{foo}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems the program R is used for doing statistical calculations. That program calculates values and in a .tex-file, which is a template, replaces identifiers by these values. It seems our fellow questioner is after a handy mechanism for bringing the calculated values and the .tex-file together.

Comment: @UlrichDiez The  R package knitr exists just to avoid that tangled workflow. For nothing you need to have a R session to save statistical results in some files and then retrieve in a LaTeX template . Just a single source and just pressing a single button file can  make all the R calculations, generate dynamically the LaTeX report, an produce the PDF, all at once.

Comment: Is knitr something like sweave? Where R-code is mixed with LaTeX-code and where a .tex-file gets derived from the file with the LaTeX/R-code-mix where R-code is replaced by TeX-code representing the result of the R-code? I didn't realize this and therefore misinterpreted your remark "It is not clear to me what are you trying to do exactly". Please accept my apologies. I should have realized this when seeing the `<<...,echo=FALSE>...@`-thingies. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Right, `knitr` was inspired  by Sweave and use a similar syntax in .Rnw files, but it is much more advanced package. It have syntax highlight of R code, it can run several languages as Python,  allow a lot of options for R chunks, have a built-in cache, it can be use in Rmarkdown (with another syntax) , etc.

Answer (score 1):

While I wrote the question, I identified the simple solution for it. Before `\begin{document}`—if I call the new function `R`—add `\newcommand{\R}[1]{}`.

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {bar}\R{R.foo}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: One way around your current workflow is to consider `knitr`. You'd write a mixture of markdown and R code and compile the output into a PDF (which uses LaTeX).

Comment: If you're able to find-and-replace `{}\label{R.foo}` with `{bar}\label{R.foo}`, why not just replace it with `{bar}`? That way you don't have to now replace it with `{bar}\R{R.foo}` and set `\newcommand{\R}[1]{}`...?